# Repeated pattern in a SPARQL query that can't (?) be reduced to a property path

Tags: sparql

I have this SAPRQL query that is growing because there are multiple paths by which  Biosamples can be converted into ProcessedSamples.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I will abstract out the pattern of N different Processes linking the Biosample to the ProcessedSample through various intermediate inputs and outputs. I can't imagine how it could be reduced to a property path.

I am interested in pure SPARQL solutions. I will also start working on query generation in Python with [SPARQL Burger unions](https://github.com/panmitz/SPARQL-Burger#3-create-a-union-of-graph-patterns).

```
PREFIX nmdc: <https://w3id.org/nmdc/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
select 
distinct 
?Biosample ?process_type_1 ?process_type_2  ?process_type_3  ?process_type_4 ?ProcessedSample 
where {
    ?ProcessedSample a nmdc:ProcessedSample .
    ?Biosample a nmdc:Biosample .
    {
        ?Process1 a ?process_type_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?Biosample ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?ProcessedSample .
    }
    union
    {
        ?Process1 a ?process_type_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?Biosample ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_1 .
        ?Process2 a ?process_type_2 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?ProcessedSample .
    }
    union
    {
        ?Process1 a ?process_type_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?Biosample ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_1 .
        ?Process2 a ?process_type_2 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_2 .
        ?Process3 a ?process_type_3 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_2 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?ProcessedSample .
    }
    union
    {
        ?Process1 a ?process_type_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?Biosample ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_1 .
        ?Process2 a ?process_type_2 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_1 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_2 .
        ?Process3 a ?process_type_3 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_2 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?intermediate_3 .
        ?Process4 a ?process_type_4 ;
                  nmdc:has_input ?intermediate_3 ;
                  nmdc:has_output ?ProcessedSample .
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your triplestore?

Comment: If it is GraphDB, then check https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/graph-path-search.html

Comment: I suppose you also would like to have an ordered list of process types?

Answer (score 3):

I made a small sample dataset and tested this query, which seems to work for me.

```
PREFIX nmdc: <https://w3id.org/nmdc/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?Biosample ?ProcessedSample (GROUP_CONCAT(STR(?type)) AS ?concat)
WHERE {
        ?ProcessedSample a nmdc:ProcessedSample .
        ?Biosample a nmdc:Biosample .
    
        ?pStart nmdc:has_input ?Biosample ;
            (nmdc:has_output/^nmdc:has_input)* ?intermediate .
    
        ?intermediate a ?type ;
            (nmdc:has_output/^nmdc:has_input)* ?final .
    
        ?final nmdc:has_output ?ProcessedSample  .
    
    }
GROUP BY ?Biosample ?ProcessedSample
```

So here what we do is start with `?Biosample`, then follow a chain of `nmdc:hasOutput` followed by a reverse `nmdc:hasInput` to the next process, if there is one, calling it `?intermediate`. We find out the type of `?intermediate`.

Finally we move onto `?final` which will have as output `?ProcessedSample`.
Note that because we use `*` in the property path `?pStart`, `?intermediate`, and `?final` may all be bound to the same process.